# Firefox cannot select checkbox "Always open default" with containers add on

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I'm using the [Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) add-on for Firefox.

I would like to open each new tab automatically in the default container for this window, in this case `Personal`.

But I'm unable to check the checkbox `Always open in Personal`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Menu for Multi-Account Containers add-on]

More generally, is there a setting to have a particular window be associated with one container, e.g. `Work`, and another window be associated with another container, e.g. `Personal`?

Comment: Fill a bugreport to Mozilla.

Comment: This looks like the add-on the OP is talking about: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/

Comment: @jpaugh yes it's the containers add on you linked to

Comment: FYI found a bug report for this here:https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues/1194

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That checkbox doesn't do what you're looking for.  Afaict, there isn't a way to default a window to a particular container.

What that checkbox does is associate the *currently open website* with a particular container. (It can't be the default non-container, either, per [the bug](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues/1194) mentioned by pixelrevision.)  If you don't have any website open, the checkbox is disabled, as you describe.

Answer (score -2):

I have tried it works when I open the website and able to tick the checkbox. Looks like it’s to set container to open the website as default instead open the container on first launch. May be set the default startup page to Google and set the Google to open with container by default.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiJju.png)